# How to always show buttons on bottom left (ASP.NET Core with Bootstrap)

Tags: asp.net, razor, bootstrap-4

I have an ASP.NET Core Web app, with two buttons enabling search result navigation. I am trying to figure out how to *always* show the buttons at the bottom left-hand side. How can I do this easily?

Here is an image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyWwE.png

Here is the code.

```
var prevDisabled = !Model.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : ""; 
var nextDisabled = !Model.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : "";

<a asp-action="Index" 
asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]" 
asp-route-page="@(Model.PageIndex - 1)" asp-route-currentFilterSearchBy="@ViewData["CurrentFilterSearchBy"]" currentFilterLocation="@ViewData["CurrentFilterLocation"]"
asp-route-currentFilterItem="@ViewData["CurrentFilterItem"]"
class="btn btn-default @prevDisabled" style="bottom:0;">
Previous
</a>
<a asp-action="Index"
asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]"
asp-route-page="@(Model.PageIndex + 1)"
asp-route-currentFilterSearchBy="@ViewData["CurrentFilterSearchBy"]"
asp-route-currentFilterLocation="@ViewData["CurrentFilterLocation"]"
asp-route-currentFilterItem="@ViewData["CurrentFilterItem"]"
class="btn btn-default @nextDisabled" style="bottom:0;">
Next
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the grid system of bootstrap?
You need make next as sample:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
            <div>CARD</div>
            <div>
                <a asp-action="Index" 
                    asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]" 
                    asp-route-page="@(Model.PageIndex - 1)" asp-route-currentFilterSearchBy="@ViewData["CurrentFilterSearchBy"]" currentFilterLocation="@ViewData["CurrentFilterLocation"]"
                    asp-route-currentFilterItem="@ViewData["CurrentFilterItem"]"
                    class="btn btn-default @prevDisabled" style="bottom:0;">
                    Previous
                </a>
                <a asp-action="Index"
                    asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]"
                    asp-route-page="@(Model.PageIndex + 1)"
                    asp-route-currentFilterSearchBy="@ViewData["CurrentFilterSearchBy"]"
                    asp-route-currentFilterLocation="@ViewData["CurrentFilterLocation"]"
                    asp-route-currentFilterItem="@ViewData["CurrentFilterItem"]"
                    class="btn btn-default @nextDisabled" style="bottom:0;">
                    Next
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
            CONTENT
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't use it properly. :-) You are awesome - worked perfectly.